# Are there 'special' screwdrivers for opening plastic enclosures?

Tags: tv-antenna, access-panel

My new apartment comes with TV outputs ... which are mostly useless in the era of DTV and with our national cable networks being decommissioned. They're connected to a splitter that's connected to... I'm not actually sure what

According to the schematics, thesplitter is in this box, and I can't really see anything going in, other than the trunking. I *might* have use for MOCA for these, since the ethernet connections terminate there too.

[image]

I tried to open it with an (admittedly too small) screwdriver and munged up one of the plastic bolts a little. I'm wondering if there's a 'proper' tool for this - and what its called

Comment: maybe they are not bolts, but 1/4 turn latches .. use a largest flat blade screwdriver that fits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use a larger screwdriver.

with two of the screws fully out and the other two half undone the lid  will hinge open

[image]

image credit amazon.

But, as some bozo has mounted it sideways, you may as well undo all the screws

Comment: Funny thing is... its probably mounted side ways in.. 100s of residential units. I'll try it the next time I'm over - I've found a much wider screwdriver in my leatherman which MIGHT work, but I'd almost swear there's a special tool for this

Comment: If the hinge ones are on the bottom that works fine. Only if the hinge ones are on the top is it a pain. Or the both hinge (hard to be sure in the picture, but looks like it) so just take out the top ones and loosen the bottom ones and try.

Comment: I tend to find having a shelf in front of box get in the way of my wrists and forearms,

Comment: No hinge, its 4 screws and it 'just' popped up. The 'big' leatherman screwdriver did the trick though.